# Standard Deviation Calculator (Java)

Tags: java

I currently have to write a program to calculate the mean and standard deviation for an array of ten numbers. The mean calculateMean method seems to work just fine, but there is a flaw in my logic in my calculateStandardDeviation method. Not sure where exactly that lies. Any advice/pointers would be greatly appreciated!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in); 
    System.out.println("Please enter ten numbers: "); 

    double [] set = new double [10]; 

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        set[i] = input.nextDouble(); 
    }

    /*for (double j: set){
        System.out.println(j);
    }*/

    System.out.println(calculateMean(set)); 
    System.out.println(calculateStandardDeviation(set));

}

public static double calculateMean(double[] m){
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<m.length; i++){
        sum = sum + m[i];
    }
    double mean = (sum) / (m.length); 
    return mean; 
}

public static double calculateStandardDeviation(double[] sd){

    double sum = 0;
    double newSum = 0; 
    double [] newArray = new double [10]; 

    for (int i = 0; i<sd.length; i++){
        sum = sum + sd[i];
    }
    double mean = (sum) / (sd.length); 

    for (int j = 0; j<sd.length; j++){
        newArray[j] = ((sd[j] - mean) * (sd[j] - mean)); 
        newSum = newSum + newArray[j]; 
    }
    double squaredDiffMean = (newSum) / (sd.length); 
    double standardDev = (Math.sqrt(squaredDiffMean)); 

    return standardDev; 
}
```

Comment: Why do you set the size of `newArray` to ten when the size of `sd` might be something other than that? Set the size of `newArray` to match the size of the `sd` array. (Also, seeing as you've lovingly created a method called `calculateMean(double[])` you really ought to call that when you calculate the mean in your `calculateStandardDevation(double[])` method.)

Comment: Not bad, but two suggestions: (1) Check to make sure the array isn't null or empty when you calculate mean, (2) Your standard deviation calculation doesn't look optimal to me. There's an easier way - less code.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "there is a flaw in my logic in my calculateStandardDeviation method" ? Are the results incorrect? I ran your program with an input of 2,4,4,4,5,5,7,9,9,10 and it gave 5.9
2.5475478405713994 as mean and standard deviation respectively. That seems correct?

Comment: I said I could write it more clearly with less code.  I didn't say "incorrect".  Read it again, please.

Comment: If my answer addressed all your questions, please [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, why do you set the size of `newArray` to a static number? It shouldn't be. Also, that second array is unnecessary. But even if you did need a second array, you should change `new double[10]` to `new double[sd.length]`.

So change the following function to this:

```
public static double calculateStandardDeviation(double[] sd) {

    double sum = 0;
    double newSum = 0; 

    for (int i = 0; i < sd.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + sd[i];
    }
    double mean = (sum) / (sd.length); 

    for (int j = 0; j < sd.length; j++) {
        // put the calculation right in there
        newSum = newSum + ((sd[j] - mean) * (sd[j] - mean)); 
    }
    double squaredDiffMean = (newSum) / (sd.length); 
    double standardDev = (Math.sqrt(squaredDiffMean)); 

    return standardDev; 
}
```

More points:

- In your second loop, you don't need to use `j` instead of `i`. They are in different scopes, so you *can* reuse `i`. The only time you can't is if it is a loop inside another loop.
- Instead of `((sd[j] - mean) * (sd[j] - mean))`, you can use the [Math#pow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,%20double)) static function for the calculation, like `Math.pow((sd[j] - mean), 2)`
- You don't need first loop at all. You already have a function to calculate the mean, so why do it again in your other function? Just use the first function in this one too.
- You should have checks at the top of your mean and SD functions to see if the length of the array is 0. Otherwise, you could divide by 0. Now, this won't be a problem with your code because you force 10 inputs from the user, but in general, this is good practice.

So then the "better" code would be the following:

```
public static double calculateMean(double[] m){
    if (m.length == 0) return 0; // don't divide by zero!

    // ... the rest of your stuff
}

public static double calculateStandardDeviation(double[] sd){

    if (sd.length == 0) return 0; // don't divide by zero!

    double sum = 0;

    double mean = calculateMean(sd);

    for (int i = 0; i<sd.length; i++){
        sum = sum + (sd[i] - mean) * (sd[i] - mean);
    }
    double squaredDiffMean = (sum) / (sd.length); 
    double standardDev = (Math.sqrt(squaredDiffMean)); 

    return standardDev; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. The only reason why I have a static array is because the assignment that I am completing this for calls for an array of ten.

Comment: I also understand that the for loops are in different scopes, but for my own clarity I just prefer to use different variables.

Comment: @user5499487 Yes, in this specific code, it can be 10. But as a general concept, there's no reason to limit the length of the array. It should work for any array size. But what makes you think there's an error in your code?

Comment: A length check could also help - e.g. if (sd.length ==1) return 0

Comment: @MojoJojo that might be technically more efficient in that one specific case, but very slightly, and would make the program worse in general. The algorithm already returns `0` when the length is `1`, so it really doesn't solve a problem. However, a check for length being `0` would be correct.